# getline() not working second time in a while loop

Tags: c++, while-loop

First is the while loop code:

```
void Menu() {
    string option;
    char yes;
    yes='y';
    while (yes == 'y') {
    cout << "Commands: buy, sell, directory, and exit: ";
    getline (cin, option);
    if (option == "buy") {
        ...
    }
    ...
cout << "Do you wish to continue? Press y for yes, n for no: ";
cin >> yes;
}
}
```

In this when the loop goes off a second time (press yes) it skips back to:

```
cout << "Do you wish to continue? Press y for yes, n for no: ";
```

I think it has somewhat to do with providing an answer to getline() early but I don't know where.

I.E:

```
Here is the menu: Commands: buy, sell, directory, and exit: buy
Enter a player's I.D: 2
Here is your current money after purchasing Player X: 150000
Do you wish to continue? Press y for yes, n for no: y
Commands: buy, sell, directory, and exit: Do you wish to continue? Press y for yes, n for no: y
Commands: buy, sell, directory, and exit: Do you wish to continue? Press y for yes, n for no:
```

The intention is to repeat the loop when pressing yes (including being able to enter another command).

Answer (score 12):

```
cin >> yes;
```

Right there, the user enters a letter, let's say 'y'.  Then hits enter.  This stores 2 characters in the input buffer, 'y' and '\n'.  The 'y' gets stored in yes, but the '\n' remains.  When you get to here again:

```
getline (cin, option);
```

Since there's already a newline character in the buffer, getline has what it's looking for, and doesn't need to prompt the user.

There are a few solutions to this.  You could add a call to `cin.ignore()` after `cin >> yes`.  Or you could make `yes` a string, and use `getline` instead of `operator>>` there.

Answer (score 1):

If you are taking inputs for different test cases this method works: Put "cin.ignore()" after taking the number of Test cases. Example:-

```
int main() {
    
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    
    cin.ignore();     //putting of ignore function
    while(t--)
    {
        string str;
        getline(cin,str);
        
        cout<<str<<"\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because `\n` will remain in the buffer after the first `cin`. You can solve this problem by adding an empty `cin.get()` between two consecutive reads. Just put a counter, and a first verification:

```
//(...)

int count = 0;

//(...)

while (yes == 'y') 
{
    if (count == 0)
    {
        // "Clear the very first input"
        cin.get();
    }

    cout << "Commands: buy, sell, directory, and exit: ";
    getline (cin, option);
    if (option == "buy") {
        ...
    }
    ...
    cout << "Do you wish to continue? Press y for yes, n for no: ";
    cin >> yes;

    // Increment the counter
    count++;
}
```

Fonts:

[Can't get char from cin.get()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18696531/cant-get-char-from-cin-get)

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the cin.Clear() or just cin.ignore() does not work. I have not researched why but I have found another answer. To my understanding there are still things in the buffer that cause this. like the one of the other posters stated...

```
cin.ignore(cin.rdbuf()->in_avail(),'\n');
```

will solve the problem. Place this line of code right before your first getline statement after asking the first question.

http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/20206/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that cin is leaving a newline in the stream which the getline() call reads.

Try adding cin.ignore(1,'\n'); after the cin to remove that newline. :)

Answer (score 0):

cin.clear() after getline. it works for me.