# Can't get char from cin.get()

Tags: c++, cin

I'm working through some beginner exercises on c++, and this has me stumped. I can enter a number, but I don't get the option to enter a character afterwards, and it skips to the final line.

I know I can use cin >> symbol, but i would like to know why this isn't working.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    cout << "Enter a number:\n";
    int number;
    cin >> number;

    char symbol;
    cout << "Enter a letter:\n";
    cin.get(symbol);

    cout << number << " " << symbol << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think your symbol variable gets the carriage return i.e. `\n` as a value. Hint: check what you get as output for your final `cout`

Comment: Ah. You're right. Adding another cin.get() before the symbol one fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\n` will remain in the buffer after the first `cin`. You can solve this problem by adding an empty `cin.get()` between two consecutive reads.

```
cin.get(string1,maxsize);
cin.get();
cin.get(string2,maxsize);
```

Or you can use `fflush`:

```
cin.get(string1,maxsize);
fflush(stdin);
cin.get(string2,maxsize);
```

Comment: More generally, `>>` does **formatted** input; in part that means that it skips leading whitespace. `get()` does **unformatted** input, which does not ignore whitespace. Mixing formatted and unformatted input can easily lead to confusion.

Comment: Note that using fflush on a stream that is not an update or an output stream is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 9):

You should remove `'\n'` from stream, remained after entering the number:

```
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Without it you will read newline character. You could check that with:

```
std::cout << (symbol == '\n') << std::endl;
```